# the probability that a chi square distribution smaller than its degree of freedom

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a $\chi_k^2$-distributed random variable, then is there any explicit form for the probability
$$\mathbb{P} (X < k)?$$
In particular, I'm interested in the asymptotic value of 
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\mathbb{P} (X < k). $$
Thank you.

Comment: Using the central limit theorem, you can show that this asymptotic value is $0.5$.

Comment: According to the central limit theorem $\lim_{k \to \infty}\chi_k^2\sim\mathcal N(k,2k)$

Answer (score 0):

The asymptotic value is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Let $X_i$ be an i.i.d. sequence of standard Gaussian random variables. Then $Y_k = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^k X_i^2 \sim \chi^2_k$. Now note that

$$P(Y_k < k) = P(Y_k \le k) = P\left(k^{-1/2}(Y_k - k) \le 0\right) \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{2}$$
because $k^{-1/2}(Y_k - k) \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0, 2)$ by the central limit theorem.

Comment: Exactly, thank you very much.

Comment: BTW, did you graduate from UNC?

Comment: No, I graduated in Germany.